# Pool de aplicativos ASP.net MVC parando sozinho

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Tenho uma aplicação `ASP.NET MVC` que está rodando em cima do `IIS` na versão 10.0. Quando há várias conexões simultâneas (3~5 conexões) ele simplesmente para o pool da aplicação apresentando a seguinte mensagem no log:

> O pool de aplicativos 'AplicacaoTeste' está sendo automaticamente desabilitado devido a uma série de falhas em um ou mais processos que atendem a esse pool de aplicativos.

```
Nome do aplicativo com falha: w3wp.exe, versão: 10.0.16299.15, carimbo de data/hora: 0xa832291b
Nome do módulo com falha: unknown, versão: 0.0.0.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x00000000
Código de exceção: 0xc00000fd
Deslocamento da falha: 0x33dcd158
ID do processo com falha: 0x23f0
Hora de início do aplicativo com falha: 0x01d4a100c748cab6
Caminho do aplicativo com falha: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Caminho do módulo com falha: unknown
ID do Relatório: 09509345-5f13-472a-ae7f-5c4f7dd384d0
Nome completo do pacote com falha: 
ID do aplicativo relativo ao pacote com falha:
```

A mensagem apresentada acima é muito genérica e não passa nenhuma informação palpável.

Dúvida:
Onde eu posso obter mais informações sobre o que realmente aconteceu ou esteja causando isso? Alguém já passou por isso e sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Verifique log do servidor, lá deve ter o motivo.

Comment: Essa mensagem já foi retirada do log do servidor amigo. Vou colocar um adendo à mensagem de erro mas não vai adicionar muita informação.

Comment: Não existe o log por completo, para saber quando executo o seu site algum processo envolvido é oneroso? Qual processo executa o seu site para? falta dizer muita coisa

Comment: Veja o log completo adicionado

Comment: Qual processo você executa? é um processo custoso, que demora para executar? Ta com cara de servidor mau configurado.

Comment: Todos os processos contidos na aplicação são simples, nada custoso demais para processar simultaneamente

Comment: Eu acho que é falha no servidor pela mensagem. Talvez reinstalando funciona corretamente esses são problemas locais difícil reproduzir.